# what does THCudaTensor_data ( and THC in general ) do?

Tags: pytorch, torch

The program I am inspecting uses pytorch to load weights and cuda code to do the computations with the weights. My understanding of THC library is how tensors are implemented in the backend of pytorch ( and torch, maybe? ).

1. how is THC implemented ( I would really appreiciate some details if possible )?
2. what does THCudaTensor_data( THC_state, THCudaTensor* ) do? ( from the way it is used in the code, it seems like it is used to convert pytorch's tensor to an array in cuda. if this is the case, then would the function preserve all elements and the length of the array?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not exactly sure of the inner-workings of THCudaTensor_data, but the behaviour that was tripping me up was: for n-dimensional tensor, THCudaTensor_data returns a flattened 1D array of the tensor.

Hope this helps

Comment: Please remember to come back in a couple of days and accept this answer, and encourage your friend CMU to do the same